# Delphi: Datasnap Identifying User from Server Methods Unit

Tags: delphi, datasnap

How can I determine the User that initiated one of my functions that I have created in my Server Methods Unit?

Answer (score 1):

in the ServerContainerUnit or WebModuleUnit (ISAPI),

---

DSAuthenticationManager.onUserAuthenticate procedure or TDSServer.onConnect ect...,

---

use  TDSSessionManager.GetThreadSession.PutData('**UserName**',User); identify current user to DSSession,

---

in your Servermethods unit functions, you can use TDSSessionManager.GetThreadSession.GetData('**UserName**')from the DSSession what you saved onUserAuthenticate or other procedure.

---

Tested on DataSnap REST ISAPI, work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `TDSSessionManager.GetThreadSession.Username` if you have authentication enabled.